# How do I place the canvas created by p5js inside the <main> tag area

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I can't put the WEBgl canvas of p5js, with width 100% and height 100%, inside the `<section>` tag. This tag is inside the `<main>` tag, which in turn is inside the `<body`> tag. As per the html code.

My layout has a right area (right `<aside>`), a center area (`<main>`) and a left area (`<aside>` left). I want the canvas to be inside the central area, as shown in FIGURE 1 below. The p5js canvas works normally in html, but it is next to the `<aside>` tag on the right, as shown in FIGURE 2.

Another thing, in addition to placing the canvas inside the central area (`<main>` tag), I need it to have width: 100% and height:100% inside `<main>`.

OBS: the tag `<canvas>` would solve the problem of being inside main and with width: 100% and height:100%. However, I don't think I could use webgl or p5js on it. That's why I created the canvas via p5js.

**FIGURE 1**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMgXM.png)

**FIGURE 2**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kU4YK.png)

The html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Teste</title>

    <script src="p5/p5.js"></script>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body> 
    
    <main>        
        <aside class="sides">
            <p>RIGHT</p>            
        </aside>

        <section id="_center">
            <p>CENTER</p>
            <!-- <script src="sketch.js"></script> -->
        </section>

        <aside class="sides">            
            <p>LEFT</p>
        </aside>

    </main>
</body>

</html>
```

The CSS code is:

```
@charset "UTF-8";

:root {
    
    --cor0: #EEEEEE;
    --cor1: #E0E0E0;
    --cor2: #E0E0E0;
    --cor3: #EDEDED;
    --cor4: #C7C7C7;

    --fonte-padrão: Arial, Verdana, Helvetica, sans-verif;
}


* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0%;
}

html,
body {
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
}

main {
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 70%;
    width: auto;
    padding: 3px;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
    border: 0.5px solid black;
}

main aside.sides {
    background-color: var(--cor2);
    width: 5%;
    min-width: 150px;
    min-height: 500px;
}

main section#_center {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, var(--cor0), var(--cor4));
    width: 90%;
    min-width: 500px;
    min-height: 500px;
}
```

And sketch.js from p5js is:

```
function setup(){
  cnv = createCanvas(600, 600, WEBGL);  
}


//function to draw with or whithout loop, use redraw() if no loop
function draw() {
  background(0, 110, 255)
}
```

Comment: The **<cavnas>** created is an HTML element?

Comment: Because if so, you can use ``document.append`` to put it inside ``_center``.

Comment: I solved the first problem. just put the following code: `function setup(){ cnv = createCanvas(600, 600, WEBGL); cnv.parent("_center"); }` So, the canvas was inside the `<section id="_center">` tag. 

But, I still couldn't solve the following problem, which is to make the canvas have width: 100% and height: 100% of the tag `<section id="_center">`.

Comment: I think you could create a css id called ``#cavnas`` and apply ``width: 100%;`` and ``height: 100%`` to it.

Comment: Then make its parent a **<div>** with id ``cavnas``.